# measure cost of thread migration?

Tags: c++, multithreading, migration

info:

1. i'm coding in C/C++;
2. i have a multi-threaded program and i want to optimize it, i.e. reduce cpu time (computed by 'clock_gettime' with 'CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID' specified) consumed by each function;
3. my guess is, it may fit my purpose by using 'pthread_setaffinity_np' to bind each thread to its specific CPU, i.e. avoid cost resulted from thread migration;
4. premiliary test shows that my guess seems right.

questions:

1. what's the cost of thread migration? is binding thread to a CPU really helpful?
2. is it possible to know how many times thread migration happened during a process execution? if possible, how to do it ?

Answer (score 6):

> what's the cost of thread migration?

It increases the likelihood of cache misses; after migration, it will probably be accessing a different cache, which will not contain its recently used data. How much this costs depends on how much it would otherwise take advantage of the cache.

> is binding thread to a CPU really helpful?

In some circumstances it can help; in others, it can hurt performance. For example, threads bound to the same core must wait for each other, while unbound threads could be scheduled immediately on any available core. If you really need that level of performance tuning, then you'll need to measure the effect.

> is it possible to know how many times thread migration happened during a process execution? if possible, how to do it ?

It's platform dependent. On Linux, you can see many scheduling statistics (including migrations) in `/proc/<pid>/sched`